# How to pass errors in template from route?

Tags: ember.js

I do 'server side validation'. In route in method 'catch' get errors from server. And I want pass this errors in template.
How to pass errors in template from route?

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.createRecord('project');
  },

  actions: {
    save(project) {
      var router = this;
      var errors = router.controllerFor('project.new').get('errors')
      project.save().then(function(project){
        router.transitionTo('projects.show', project);
      }).catch(function(resp) {
        // how to pass this errors in template ???? 
        console.log(resp.errors);
      });
    }
  }, 
});
```

From router.js

```
this.route('projects', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', { path: '/:project_id' });
 });
```

From Component

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    save() {
      this.project.set('colors', colors);
      this.sendAction('save');
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Closure Actions](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/#toc_passing-the-action-to-the-component)! (Assuming a recente version of - Ember 1.13+). Closure actions can have a return value, unlike regular actions.

On your template you do:

```
{{my-component mySave=(action 'save')}}
```

And in your component you do

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data'

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
   save() {
     this.project.set('colors', colors);
     let result = this.attrs.mySave();
     //do something with result
   }
 },
 ...
 });
```

And then in your controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

actions: {
  save(project) {
    var router = this;
    var errors = router.controllerFor('project.new').get('errors')
    project.save().then(function(project){
    router.transitionTo('projects.show', project);
  }).catch(function(resp) {
    return resp.errors;
  });
 }
 }, 
});
```

I would also recommend [this article on Closure Actions](http://alisdair.mcdiarmid.org/ember-closure-actions-have-return-values/) which is very helpful.

EDIT: I initially replied with the action being on the route (as in your example) but @Kitler correctly reminded that closure actions communicate with the controller or another component. I don't know if that's an option for the OP?

Comment: Closure actions communicate with the controller not the route.

Comment: @Kitler is right, closure actions communicate with the controller. Sorry for the mistake!